# Link multiply output to color hue value input

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I'm trying to get a multiply patch output value change only the hue of a color.  I want to keep saturation and luminance set to a fixed value.

[image]

With my current configuration it is only changing luminance.  It looks like is changing all RGB channels equally.  What would be the correct way to manipulate HSL channels individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the solution. I was missing the 'pack' patch. This is a very useful patch I wasn't aware of.  This is how my workflow ended up at the end:

[image]